# Upload to amazon s3 very slow taking time

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using python-flask application with **boto3** library to upload image on Amazon S3 but for 1MB size - 3MB size it taking 16-18 seconds to upload.
What i am missing please suggest.

```js
function readFile(evt) {
     var file = evt.target.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     output_format = "jpg";
     reader.onload = function(event) {
         var i = document.getElementById("source_image");
             i.src = event.target.result;
             i.onload = function(){
                 image_width=$(i).width(),
                 image_height=$(i).height();

                 if(image_width > image_height){
                     i.style.width="320px";
                 }else{
                     i.style.height="300px";
                 }
                 i.style.display = "block";
                 console.log("Image loaded");
             }
     };

     console.log("Filename:" + file.name);
     console.log("Filesize:" + (parseInt(file.size) / 1024) + " Kb");
     console.log("Type:" + file.type);
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);

     return false;
 }
  
  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_form" action="/updateuser" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Choose file</label>
  <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
  <img id="source_image">
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="uploadimage">
</form>
```

**Below is my python code**

I imported S3_KEY, S3_SECRET, S3_BUCKET from config file , creating instance of boto3 client & by using **s3.upload_fileobj()** uploading file to Amazon S3.

```
    import boto3
    from config import S3_KEY, S3_SECRET, S3_BUCKET
    # Ajax function to support upload image call from UI
    @app.route('/user/uploadimage',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def uploadimage():
        print "In uploadimage()"
        starttime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print "Start Monitoring uploadimage()",starttime
        try:
            s3 = boto3.client(
                "s3",
                aws_access_key_id=S3_KEY,
                aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
        try:
            file = request.files['file']
            s3.upload_fileobj(
                file,
                S3_BUCKET,
                file.filename,
                ExtraArgs={
                    "ACL": "public-read",
                    "ContentType": file.content_type
                }
            )
            print "File uploaded successfully"
            print "Stop Monitoring uploadimage()",(int(round(time.time() * 1000))-starttime)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error while Saving Image on Amazon S3 : ", e)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not because of your internet upload speed? Try running a [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net)

Comment: By using SpeedTest , i got 36ms for PING,Download-7.85Mbps,Upload-0.46Mbps

Comment: I added start and stop time in that example, can u please check with time?

Comment: But for 1-3 MB if takes 10-15 sec then for 10 mb i have to wait for 100-120 sec means approx. 2 mins. its more

Answer (score 1):

```
0.5Mbps / 8 = 0,0625 MBps 

1MB / 0,0625 ~ 16 sec
```

I see nothing wrong with the speed considering your internet connection... it should actually take more time

Comment: Then how the others will be uploading 1- 2 GB in S3 using btoto3 with less time as compare to this.

Comment: With a good internet connection... my own speed test is about 40 Mbps that is 5MBps... it's a lot more than what you have...
i would take 204 sec to upload 1GB file.
Amazon can give you all the avaiability you need but your own connection speed is the bottleneck

Comment: @VinayakMahajan, based on your ISP you can ask for your Upload and Download speed to be evened i.e. to increase your Upload by taking a hit to your download.

Comment: Ok. I will ask to ISP about this and will let u know soon. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Based on your finding from SpeedTest, it appears there is nothing wrong with your internet.

Let me explain, your upload speed is 0.46**Mbps** which means your upload speed in Megabytes per second is: `0.46/8 = 0,0575 MBps`

Since you have 3 **Megabytes** with the speed of 0,0575**MBps** it should take you about 17~18 seconds.

Check for any software on your machine that might be introducing a bottleneck for upload speed.

Comment: Ok, But 17-18 seconds its not more time for just 1MB ?

Comment: @VinayakMahajan, yes I appreciate that but the formula and the explanation above does not take into account any overhead; meaning there is no data loss and no other applications are uploading anything.